# Find a conformal mapping from the quarter-disk $Q=\{ |z|<1 : rez>0,im z>0 \}$ onto the upper half plane set $U=\{im z>0\}$

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry, mobius-transformation

> Find a conformal mapping from the quarter-disk $Q=\{ |z|<1 : rez>0,im z>0 \}$ onto the upper half plane set $U=\{im z>0\}$

I'm guided through this problem:

**First** I need to find the image of the quarter disk $Q=\{ |z|<1 : rez>0,im z>0 \}$ by $f(z)=z^2$?

*My answer to this is a semi-circle (edit:disk), with unit radius.*

Now I need to find the **map** of the halfdisk $D=\{ |z-1|<1 :im z>0 \}$ onto the the first quadrant $\{im z>0, rez>0\}$.

I'm stuck on this bit:

I tried: rewriting the halfdisk as $1+e^{it}$ for $0\leq t \leq 2\pi$ , but I didn't get far.

Lastly, I need to somehow put the first two together, to get a map from the quarter disk onto the upper halfplane

Comment: Your words "semi-circle" are less appropriate that "semi-disc" (in analogy to "quarter-disc").

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant disk

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the map $f_1=z^2$, then the map $f_2=-{1\over 2}(z+z^{-1})$.

Comment: I'm assuming the second map is for the mapping of halfdisk onto the 1st quadrant. Then I'll need to take the composition. Is that right?

Comment: First map takes the quarter-disk into upper half-disk. The second takes the upper half-disk into the upper half-space.

Comment: @Ruzayqat did you mean $f_2=-\frac{1}{2} (z+z^{-1})$ or $f_2=\frac{-1}{2 (z+z^{-1})}$, at first I thought it is the first one but I couldn't show that it maps the upper half-disk into the upper half-space.

Comment: This absolutely refers to the relatively standard map $f_2(z) = -{1\over 2}(z + z^{-1})$, so I've edited the answer to reflect this.