# Building conformal maps

Tags: complex-analysis

I am self-studying complex analysis, and I am having a difficult time geometrically building conformal maps. I would like to find a conformal bijection from what I am calling the "indented quarter-plane"
$$U_1=\{z: \textrm{re}(z)<0, \textrm{im}(z)>0, |z|>1\}$$
To the open unit disc $\mathbb{D}$. ($U_1$ looks like the second quadrant of the complex plane, with a bite mark in the bottom right corner.) Here is my idea so far:

1. First, use a $\frac{5\pi}{4}$-radian clockwise rotation map. This takes $U_1$ to the region:
   $$U_2=\{z: -\frac{\pi}{4}<\arg(z)<\frac{\pi}{4}, |z|>1\}$$
2. Now, use $z \mapsto z^2$. This doubles arguments and takes $U_2$ to the positive-real half plane with a bite in it:
   $$U_3 = \{z: \textrm{re}(z)>0, |z|>1\}$$
3. (This is the hard part) Somehow fill in the hole to get
   $$U_4 = \{z:\textrm{re}(z)>0\}$$
4. Use a Mobius transformation to take the half-plane to the disc.

How might one construct a conformal map from $U_1 \to \mathbb{D}$? Was the above approach a good idea or was it totally off?

Answer (score 1):

The map $z\mapsto-\frac1z$ maps $U_1$ to the positive quarter-circle $|z|<1,0<\arg z<\pi/2$. Then apply the map [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1755904/357390), $z\mapsto-\frac{z^2+1/z^2}2$, which maps the quarter-circle to the upper half-plane. Then use $z\mapsto\frac{iz+1}{z+i}$ to map the upper half-plane to $\mathbb D$.

The $f_2$ map in the linked answer, $z\mapsto z+\frac1z$, is sometimes called the Joukowsky transform.

Comment: Nice. I should have considered inversion first.